# Has "hacker" definitely gained a negative connotation?

Tags: word-usage, pejorative-language, connotation, semantic-shift

The American Heritage Dictionary defines a ***[hacker](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/hacker)*** as:

> - One who is proficient at using or programming a computer; a computer buff.
> - One who uses programming skills to gain illegal access to a computer network or file.

I was surprised to find a neutral/positive definition which, as the word history shows below, was the original connotation of the term.

Word History:

> - *Computer programmers started using the word hacker in the 1960s as a positive term for a person of skillful programming ability*. The usage probably derives from hack meaning "to chop," or from hacker, "an amateurish player, as at golf." As time went on, hacker became less positive, however. Already in the 1960s, engineering students at such universities as Cal Tech used the related noun hack to mean "an ingenious prank." *Among the pranks that some computer programmers would engage in, of course, were break-ins into other computer systems. As such break-ins attracted national attention, the media seized upon the word hacker as the label for the perpetrators—a usage that many programmers object to because they know it used to be a term of praise.*

Questions:

Has "hacker" still a neutral/positive meaning  or has it definitely gained a negative reputation?

When did this semantic change happen?

What terms  are commonly used instead of "hacker" with a positive connotation?

Comment: *As such break-ins attracted national attention, the media seized upon the word hacker as the label for the perpetrators...* . The media is to blame. The word hacker today carries so much negativity that people had to coin the phrase "ethical hacker" to play it safe!

Comment: You 'Word History' quote seems self-contradictory. It starts off saying 'as a positive term' but the next sentence 'hack...amateurish' is negative. It started off negative but has _gained_ some positive uses for skill or ingenuity.

Comment: Back when I was in college ca 1970 "hacker" still had a positive connotation inside of programming circles (and was essentially unknown outside of programming circles).  It wasn't until 5-10 years later, when computer-related crimes first started making the news, that it obtained it's negative connotation with the general public.

Comment: I'm younger than a lot of the commentators here so I don't remember the word from the pre-vilification days.  That said, my own sense is that lately the original sense is making something of a comeback and "hacker," "hacker spaces," and "lifehacks" are showing up as terms with positive connotations in general-interest publications more frequently.

Comment: @BiscuitBoy: respectfully disagree with that last part. "Ethical hacker" refers to someone who practices the same frowned-upon art as in the second definition, but does it for the good guys. It's not the same meaning as the first, original definition of "hacker" (someone clever at computers/coding). On the other hand, I agree with you in pointing the finger at the media.

Comment: Steven Levy's *Hackers: Heroes of the Computer Revolution* has a bit about the word going from a little-known positive word to a widely-known negative word. It's around [page 378 of the 25th Anniversary Edition](https://books.google.com/books?id=mShXzzKtpmEC&lpg=PP1&pg=PA379): "The hacker community still seethes at the public burning it received in 1988 at Hacker Conference 5.0, when a reporting crew from CBS News showed up ostensibly to do a story on the glory of canonical hackers--but instead ran a piece loaded with security specialists warning of the Hacker Menace."

Comment: It's even listed in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hacker), and is defined as: "someone who seeks and exploits weaknesses in a computer system or computer network".

Comment: It is almost always interpreted negatively nowadays. Even the people who are aware of the term's origin are likely to interpret it negatively since they'll assume that you're not. It *can* be used positively but typically only is in contexts where you are assumed to know what you're talking about and so are the readers/listeners.

Comment: [Here's an article](http://imranontech.com/2008/04/01/the-origin-of-hacker/) from someone claiming that the premise of the term being positive at first is false.

Comment: That first dictionary definition seems odd to me. Hacking (in its original, nonnegative meaning) isn't so much about proficiency as it is about perseverance, the ability to doggedly "hack away" at a problem to reach a solution, even if to do so requires jury-rigging parts together in an unexpected or unconventional way.

Comment: Has "banker" definitely gained a negative connotation?

Comment: At the computer magazines where I worked for many years, we regularly received criticism from readers who disliked our policy of using _hacker_ the way the uninformed public did—to refer to what our critics insisted were "crackers"—bad-guy code breakers/tinkerers/exploiters. Our reasons were (1) the word _hacker_ was widely recognized in its negative sense in general usage; and (2)  the word _cracker_ was sufficiently ambiguous (owing to its other slang meaning of "uneducated Southern white") that we would have had to define it each time we used it. So we let common usage dictate our usage.

Comment: I don't have proof to back it up, but my impression is that the negative connotation came from the crackers adopting the term for themselves, because they were "wannabe" hackers. But they weren't really very skillful, and they couldn't find any outlet for their activity than breaking into computers.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

> Has "hacker" still a neutral/positive meaning or has it definitely gained a negative reputation?

Among the general public, hacker still has a negative connotation. With the exception of "life hacks", a fairly new phenomenon, the most usual use of the work hacker in media is related people who commit crimes by computers or other advanced electronic devices.

> When did this semantic change happen?

This happened because of years (decades) of media coverage. From my understanding, it started mostly in the late 70's or early 80's, and has persisted to the current day. Since the media considers anyone that's extremely skilled with computers a hacker, and most of what they report are crimes, the negative connotation was bound to happen sooner or later.

> What terms are commonly used instead of "hacker" with a positive connotation?

Among ethical hackers, *hacker* is the preferred term, while they use negative terms for other types of "wannabees", such as "script kiddies", "crackers" (people that crack a system for malicious intent), and so on. Real hackers are offended when you include criminals in the same group as them, the same as you'd be offended if you were accused of something you didn't do. Here's the Jargon File's definition of a hacker (which is the hacker's definition of a [hacker](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/H/hacker.html)):

> hacker: n. [originally, someone who makes furniture with an axe]
>
> 1. A person who enjoys exploring the details of programmable systems and how to stretch their capabilities, as opposed to most users, who
>      prefer to learn only the minimum necessary. RFC1392, the Internet
>      Users' Glossary, usefully amplifies this as: A person who delights in
>      having an intimate understanding of the internal workings of a system,
>      computers and computer networks in particular.
> 2. One who programs enthusiastically (even obsessively) or who enjoys programming rather than just theorizing about programming.
> 3. A person capable of appreciating hack value.
> 4. A person who is good at programming quickly.
> 5. An expert at a particular program, or one who frequently does work using it or on it; as in ‘a Unix hacker’. (Definitions 1 through 5 are
>      correlated, and people who fit them congregate.)
> 6. An expert or enthusiast of any kind. One might be an astronomy hacker, for example.
> 7. One who enjoys the intellectual challenge of creatively overcoming or circumventing limitations.
> 8. [deprecated] A malicious meddler who tries to discover sensitive information by poking around. Hence password hacker, network hacker.
>      The correct term for this sense is cracker.
>
> The term ‘hacker’ also tends to connote membership in the global
>   community defined by the net (see the network. For discussion of some
>   of the basics of this culture, see the How To Become A Hacker FAQ. It
>   also implies that the person described is seen to subscribe to some
>   version of the hacker ethic (see hacker ethic).
>
> It is better to be described as a hacker by others than to describe
>   oneself that way. Hackers consider themselves something of an elite (a
>   meritocracy based on ability), though one to which new members are
>   gladly welcome. There is thus a certain ego satisfaction to be had in
>   identifying yourself as a hacker (but if you claim to be one and are
>   not, you'll quickly be labeled bogus). See also geek, wannabee.
>
> This term seems to have been first adopted as a badge in the 1960s by
>   the hacker culture surrounding TMRC and the MIT AI Lab. We have a
>   report that it was used in a sense close to this entry's by teenage
>   radio hams and electronics tinkerers in the mid-1950s.

While you can use terms like "white hat" or "ethical hacker" as a positive connotation to "outsiders," the truth is that "ethical hacker" is considered redundant, since hackers are, by the subculture's definition, ethical, and most hackers (probably) wouldn't be caught wearing a white hat, unless they really felt the need for irony.

When you're speaking about criminals, try to avoid the term "hacker," because they're not part of that global community/subculture-- there are more appropriate terms for them, even if you might have to explain what you're talking about. The correct term to use when speaking about the global community of skilled computer enthusiasts is "hacker."

Comment: Nobody mentioned "phone phreaking", blue boxes, and how hackers started accessing systems in the early 60's and 70's.

Comment: +1. The Jargon File's definition is as definitive a reference as you can get for the original meaning.  However, I'd say that "white-hat hacker" and "ethical hacker" aren't so much redundant as they're different terms than "hacker".  Both of those refer to security experts in particular, while "hacker" is much more general.

Comment: +1 for going to the Jargon File to see how those who call themselves "hacker" define the word, rather than how those who are ignorant of the culture redefined it.

Comment: A small subculture's continued insistence that 'hacker' is a positive term is a comical farce. That's not how it's used, and that's not what it means, no matter how many times they yell otherwise.

Comment: Fwiw, I think the verb form, *hack*, is still pretty neutral, at least.

Comment: @DCShannon - in community of skilled programmers, hack is a clever non-obvious solution to a complicated problem. Breaking into systems is cracking. Passwords are cracked, nod hacked.

Comment: @PeterMasiar I'm a skilled senior programmer supervising other programmers, and a hack is a poor solution put in place either as a band-aid while one tries to think of something better or because of ignorance regarding the correct solution.

Comment: @DCShannon - You are using the common culture definition of "hack", polluted by ignorant journalists who mixed up hacking and cracking. Not the **definition used by skilled coders subculture** (where "[clever] hack" has positive connotation as non-obvious solution). And you are free to use whatever definition you prefer of course. Battle for the meaning of "hack" was lost, as described in the answer, but it does not make it right, it is still a loss for our subculture, and I try to push back at least between the people who could know better. Poor solution is a "cludge".

Comment: @PeterMasiar You are correct, I am using the common definition of the word. Thank you for making my point for me.

Comment: @DCShannon Hackers coined the term, and it was abused by the media and cinema. It's not their fault. However, the original definition is still correct, and the uninformed masses that abuse the word are still in the wrong. For example, if you saw a "milling ball", and called it a "marble", it is now not magically a marble. It remains a milling ball, and is distinct and different from a marble. There's nothing comical about the abuse of a word that's 80 years old and still has the same definition in most dictionaries and with those in the know.

Comment: I'd argue with this answer's assertion regarding "the hacker's definition of a hacker". That in itself places hackers into a very particular group, in my view that's incorrect. There are many white-hat hackers who'd disagree with that categorisation and therefore with that statement.

Answer (score 27):

Ethics aside, let's stick to the word alone. Hacker is used more commonly now in everyday speech with it's original intention thanks to meme culture. I hear "Life-hacker" way more then I hear hacker ( as in someone who gains unlawful access to a computer system ) and I work in an I.T. field. The idea of life hacking takes the word hack to the days of tinkering and finding effective ways to make things work.

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question.

Comment: That is because the answer is dependent on unknown variables, of which I presented.

Comment: While I think that this answer to the question (as the question is on the "connotation" -- which is socially-defined, at least in the understanding of the question that I have) I disagree with its content. Indeed, "I work in an I.T." too and "I hear 'Life-hacker' way more then I hear hacker" too and I am pretty sure that these are correlate. Indeed, if I worked in social care or nursery I doubt I would hear that often "Life-hack" or such that much.

Comment: You're talking about a completely different word, not to mention using anecdotal evidence to support your position.  While you say you've heard "life-hacker" way more often than "hacker", I don't know that I've ever heard that particular form of the word.  Lifehack and lifehacking? Yes.  Lifehacker? No. Regardless of whether your claim about frequency is correct, talking about lifehackers when the question is about computer hackers is kind of like talking about lifeguards when someone asks a question about guards in the NFL.

Comment: In addition to the use of "lifehacking" in everyday life, there are also other specialized positive redefinitions in the business world - for example, "growth hacking", referring to the methods that startups use to launch and expand their business.

Comment: @Kevin I believe this is down to your personal exposure to the term. "Lifehacker" is certainly in usage. Lifehacker.com is a notably popular site on the subject - Alexa ranks it 166th in the USA. It's been around for several years and has certainly contributed to the expansion of the term.

Comment: @recognizer I'm familiar with it as a website, although I'd forgotten about when I wrote my previous comment.  I've just never heard or seen it used in conversation to describe a person the way hacker is used.

Comment: I wonder if "life hacking" isn't actually intended more in media-driven negative sense — e.g using "exploits" to improve your life? I often see things framed like "brushing your teeth in the shower is a way to *steal* an extra 10 minutes sleep"

Answer (score 26):

Yes, it definitely has gained a negative connotation. In much the same way as terms like "teen" or "youth", used as a noun. They are often enough used to refer to people in that group when they are doing something wrong. A small amount of googling reveals a number of news articles about "youths" and "teens" doing things wrong.

Hacker is similar, unless you are in the field of technology, you'll probably only hear the word 'hacker' used to refer to someone breaking through IT security systems.

It is used, within the field, in a positive way, simply meaning that people are using technology in a way it wasn't specifically intended to. If you go to a Hack Day, you won't be stealing data or breaking into people's bank accounts.

However, most people don't know this, but do know that people described as hackers break past security on the internet to steal data or money. So, unfortunately, it's more likely to be understood with a negative connotation.

Comment: FWIW, as a computer science major I hadn't heard the term hacker used to denote someone as a programmer until the end of my Junior year of college when a older gentlemen came in and gave a speech. It was only known to me (and my close classmates) as a person that breaks through security. Now being a CS major I knew there was good and bad hackers (whitehat/blackhat), but never a completely alternative definition.

Comment: That's roughly what I might expect. It can also mean some slap-dash or non-standard programming. To "hack it together".

Comment: Baffled by the assertion that "youth" and "teen" carry negative connotations just because the words can be found in news reports.

Comment: @dennisdeems I think that they can have negative connotations but the answer doesn't make that argument well, nor does the argument seem relevant.

Comment: @dennisdeems perhaps I wasn't completely clear, they are not always negative, but they do have a negative connotation, particularly when used as a noun. Here's just a few examples: http://wtop.com/local/2015/12/metro-police-trying-to-combat-rowdy-teen-riders/ http://www.wcpo.com/news/local-news/hamilton-county/colerain-township/rowdy-teens-refuse-to-leave-northgate-mall-six-arrested http://www.manchestereveningnews.co.uk/news/greater-manchester-news/nine-youths-banned-mcdonalds-stockport-10935539 http://www.mirror.co.uk/news/uk-news/horde-5500-drunk-fornicating-teens-6032064

Comment: I dont think that 'teen' and 'youth' suggest  the immediate negative connotation that, generally, 'hacker' conveys.

Comment: @Josh61 http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-england-tees-35408163 http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-3387078/I-didn-t-way-Gang-attack-victim-thought-going-die-beaten-pulp-35-thugs-wielding-baseball-bats-golf-clubs-confronted-stone-throwing-youths.html http://www.standard.co.uk/news/crime/two-youths-arrested-after-man-is-attacked-at-sainsburys-store-in-waterloo-a3159566.html http://www.standard.co.uk/news/crime/man-assaulted-after-confronting-youths-over-snowball-a3159331.html

Comment: Those are article where youths are held  responsible for bad actions. I don't think, as of now, the term has acquired a negative connotation because of that. In the case of Hacker the connotation is clearly negative as you clearly state in the opening line of your answer.

Comment: @Josh61 You've overused the word 'clearly' there. 

That was, actually, the gist of my answer. Neither teen, nor youth, nor hacker are inherrently negative. However, as a result of reporting, they have gained negative connotations.

Comment: You appear to say that 'hacker' is as negative as 'youth or teen' may sound. Am I correct?

Comment: I am saying that they have all gained negative connotations in the same way. If all you hear about 'teens' is drinking, drugs and violence, you will see the word and those it represents negatively. If all you see of 'hackers' is stealing personal data or actual money, you will assume hackers are, automatically, criminals.

Comment: "Yes, it definitely has gained a negative connotation." - I don't think this has been adequately supported.  Certainly within the industry the connotations aren't automatically negative.  And even in colloquial usage it's not hard to find contexts where "hack" and "hacker" are used to refer to using skill and cleverness to do something novel.  For instance, lifehack/lifehacker are obvious examples with only neutral or positive connotations.

Comment: I can easily collect news articles reporting on bad stuff done by men, women, doctors, teachers, football players.  That doesn't mean they have a negative connotation.  Whether they have a negative connotation I don't know, but citing news articles reporting on bad stuff certainly isn't any evidence to support this claim.

Comment: Had a university cancelling my hackathon there, because "hack". ugh.

Comment: @ardaozkal Sounds like the result of a negative connotation to me.

Comment: Yes, it unfortunately is.

Comment: Removing the first paragraph would substantially improve this answer.

Comment: @dennisdeems removing the first paragraph would prevent this answer from answering the question.

Comment: If removing a made-up absurdity from a post makes it a non-answer, then the post is either nonsense or wrong.

Comment: 23 Upvotes in an answer that claims "teens" and "youths" have inherent negative connotation? Today I learned that some of you watch A LOT of news and it has a much deeper effect on the subconscious than even I had (pessimistically) estimated. Interesting.

Comment: @MatthewRead while I won't disagree that it's absurd, it is entirely true. Not that young people are inherently or automatically criminal, but that when the words "youths" or "teens" are used in the press, you know the report is going to be about misdeeds. The same is true of the word "hacker", it is ridiculous but true. I'm citing a similar example. I am not in favour of this group, but I have observed that pattern in the use of language

Comment: @HC_ It's worth noting that other words for the same people. 'teenagers' or 'young people', for instance, have less of a negative connotation.

Comment: @AJFaraday That well could be true in a given demographic and I believe you; in my own experience, I'm exposed to things like "teens react" which I perceive equally neutral connotation as "senior react" or etc. I think in media catering to older demographics, "teens" being "negative," does seem possible.

Comment: Although this answer is correct in asserting that it has a negative connotation, the reference to youth and teen is so absurd that I've downvoted.

Comment: @AJFaraday: I typed "teen" in Google. Most of the hits are non-news sites either for helping teens (and their parents) as they run into life issues, or are general entertainment sites targeted at teens. Of the three news hits, one is about a teen who was murdered, one discusses biological reason teens take more risks, and the third is about why teens are leaving Facebook, with some intelligent discussion from teens. Only the second could be considered derogatory, and even then it's just statistics. Over several pages, I found a couple more news articles with similarly-varied topics.

Comment: @MichaelS Again, I didn't say it's the only connotation of the term, and neither is that true of "hacker". I don't like that use of language, I don't use the word "teen" in that way, but I have observed it, and I cited a similar example.

Comment: @AJFaraday: Your claim is that's how it's generally perceived, and you specifically cited news examples, stating that any time the words are used in the press it's going to be in a negative light, which is simply untrue. Just because there are a couple of examples of news reports about bad teens doesn't mean the term itself generally carries a negative connotation. I do see you're quoting UK news sites, but even a search for "teen" on BBC isn't all bad, though I'm having trouble loading the site for proper searching right now.

Answer (score 10):

It has gained both a **negative** connotation (which it did since almost the first time the word was published in mainstream literature) and paradoxically it has also gained a **positive** connotation (which, among the general public, is a more recent phenomenon).

The word **hacker** has recently started regaining its original meaning of someone who is skilled at problem solving and workarounds. The term **hack** itself is nowdays used to refer to creative solutions to problems. Websites like hackaday.com and lifehacker.com have been gaining popularity outside the usual geek/tech subculture especially with the rise of Facebook.

At the same time, programmers have begun to accept the term **hacker** that is used with a negative connotation when it relates to someone who exploit other people's systems. This is partly because it's easier to talk to people about computer security using the word "hacker" rather than first explain why the word "hacker" is the wrong word to use.

So depending on context, the word **hacker** can have either positive or negative connotation. When it comes to computers, you sometimes need to clarify which you mean.

Answer (score 8):

Adding to AJFaraday's answer, I can only answer your third question and the term [**white hat**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_hat_(computer_security)) (hacker) is broadly used to distinguish *ethical computer hackers* from criminal hackers. The following Wikipedia article explains:

> The term "**white hat**" in Internet slang refers to an *ethical computer
>   hacker*, or a *computer security expert*, who specializes in penetration
>   testing and in other testing methodologies to ensure the security of
>   an organization's information systems. Ethical hacking is a term
>   coined by IBM meant to imply a broader category than just penetration
>   testing. White-hat hackers may also work in teams called
>   "sneakers", red teams, or tiger teams.
>
> A *white hat hacker* breaks security for non-malicious reasons, perhaps
>   to test their own security system or while working for a security
>   company which makes security software...This classification also
>   includes individuals who perform penetration tests and vulnerability
>   assessments within a contractual agreement.

A *computer security expert* is the general term that has a positive connotation.

Answer (score 7):

I don't think the original connotation was entirely positive. A hacker would write effective code to get something done quickly, but it might not be a well-engineered solution.

Comment: Thank you for being the only one to point out the mixed bag of the original meaning of the term.

Comment: I also wondered how, especially in the 60s, anyone could divorce the choice of "hack" from the (then) common practice of calling both bad writers and less than qualified surgeons "hacks".

Comment: @Egox The positive connotation was mostly among technical geeks, who probably didn't use the literary sense much.

Answer (score 3):

Adding to Michael Kay's answer. This is a case of the word meaning different things to different groups. The programming community has always used the term differently from the general public.

The original meaning of the term "hacker" within the programming community was definitely negative. It referred to a moderately skilled programmer who was able to solve problems more by trial and error and perseverance than by having a good understanding of the problem area. And the work of hackers was suspect, because it would often fail in circumstances that the hacker had failed to consider. Programmers would sometimes refer to themselves as hackers while learning to navigate unfamiliar systems, as a way of saying that they were not yet experts. The term "hacker" was somewhat related to the term "kludge," which has retained its largely negative meaning. A hacker would be more likely to use a kludge rather than an elegant solution. But "hacker" was never completely negative the way "hack" (from which it presumably derived) is. A hacker will eventually get the problem (sort of) solved. A hack just doesn't know what he's doing.

The positive meaning started coming about around 1980, entirely through the media and entertainment industry misunderstanding the term and then popularizing the incorrect meaning out in the general culture. This new meaning then partially drifted back into the programming community. The people who "hacked into" computer systems may or may not have referred to themselves as hackers, but once it started showing up in movies, that's what they became. (At the time, I remember them being offended, and preferring the term "cracker"). But in any event, the media types considered defeating security systems to be quite difficult and somewhat glamorous, and presumed that therefore that is what the best of the best programmers would choose to do, and from that decided that the term "hacker" referred to a highly skilled programmer. And that's the meaning that the general public knows.

Within the programming community, the meaning of hacker as someone who defeats security systems has stuck, and is used ubiquitously. But the meaning of "highly skilled programmer" never took hold. It has always meant, and still means, pretty much the opposite. So you have an interesting situation where among the general public the word means one thing, but within the group that it refers to, it means something quite different.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps much of the negative connotation stems from non-native English writers adopting the word in criminal case reporting, whilst remaining clueless about its underlying, more neutral meaning.

Comment: The negative connotation has been used in the mainstream press in the US for decades. I don't recall much contribution from non-native writers.

Answer (score 0):

Back in the mid-sixties we used non-hacker to describe someone not well-versed in copying morse code, but seldom used the positive hacker to identify someone who could keep up with some very fast senders. Non-hacker migrated to a person not adept at a given task ("Barfed after 10 beers - what a non-hacker.)

Comment: I don't believe I've ever heard "hacker" connected with ham radio operation.  Do you have a reference?  (There were several good ham magazines such as *QSL* back then, and one would have expected one of them to mention the term if it were popular, as ham jargon was a frequent topic of discussion.)

Answer (score -1):

As far as computers go, "hacker" *started* with negative connotation. I find the (disorganized) campaign to bleach it (e.g. "white hat" hackers, creating the term "cracker" to take the negative connotations, etc.) a childish reaction to the reality of general perception.

"To hack" is to cleave and cut. Trying to inject benign intent is too subtle.

Comment: "Hacker" did not have a negative connotation back ca 1970.  Skilled "hackers" were admired by others in the computer biz.

Comment: And hackers were feared by the general public because what they did was criminal. That counts more than fans of would-be Jesse James

Comment: That was later.  If you know the TV show *Numbers* from a decade ago, Charlie Epps, had his specialty been computers (and had the show been shot 40 years earlier), would have been considered a "hacker" by his cohorts in the university computer center.